# Converting XAML element to Image in silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, silverlight-4.0, fjcore

i have a XAML canvas element and i need to save the canvas element and whatever in it to any image format(JPEG,PNG) with high quality, How to do that in silverlight using c#.i saw the Fjcore code but i dont get what it is doing , please explain with a code and please comment what it is doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try **Imagetools for Silverlight** library in [Codeplex](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Write%20the%20content%20of%20a%20canvas%20to%20a%20file). Here is an example on saving a canvas element to JPEG image :

```
//Convert UIElement to Image
ei = ImageExtensions.ToImage(myCanvas);

//Save the image
SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
saveDlg.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg";
saveDlg.DefaultExt = ".jpeg";
if ((bool)saveDlg.ShowDialog())
{
    using (Stream fs = saveDlg.OpenFile())
    {
        ei.WriteToStream(fs);
    }
}
```

Further information on how to use it can be found in the link above, and as I see it, looked very simple.

Comment: Actually, I haven't tried to use that library before this. Good to know it helped :)